# Encoded byte64 image causes OutOfMemoryError android

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I'm getting quite crazy with this issue:

I am getting an OutOfMemoryError everytime I open my app. At some point, it loades an image from a server, but it's encoded y a Base64 string.

Whay I do is basically:

```
decodedString = Base64.decode(imagen_codificada);

 Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, 
                            decodedString.length);
```

But i'm getting the damned OOME, everytime.

If tried with this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inSampleSize = 8;
```

Even setting options to 128, what is crazy, but still crashes...

Is there a way to reduce the size of the String codifying the image somehow before decoding it? I can't operate straightly with the image, because it's used for many other things withing the app and in desktop environments...

I attach the ERROR log:

> 12-21 10:36:27.032: E/dalvikvm-heap(5508): 10119168-byte external
>   allocation too large for this process. 12-21 10:36:27.032:
>   E/dalvikvm(5508): Out of memory: Heap Size=5823KB, Allocated=4351KB,
>   Bitmap Size=720KB, Limit=13692KB 12-21 10:36:27.032: E/dalvikvm(5508):
>   Trim info: Footprint=6343KB, Allowed Footprint=6343KB, Trimmed=520KB
>   12-21 10:36:27.032: E/GraphicsJNI(5508): VM won't let us allocate
>   10119168 bytes 12-21 10:36:27.192: E/AndroidRuntime(5508): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 12-21 10:36:27.192: E/AndroidRuntime(5508):
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

EDIT: SOLVED WITH THIS:

```
decodedString = Base64.decode(imagen_codificada);
                    System.gc();
                    BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inSampleSize = 8;
                    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedString);
                    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, 
                            options); 
                    menu.setNombreApellido(decodedByte);
```

Thanks to everyone!!

Comment: may be this one help you :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966

Comment: Hi again, I just realized I can't use decodeByteArray with the options, so I'll need to change the Byte array into a stream. I'll try and then cooment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this 
 `byte[] decodedString = (byte[])Base64.decode(imagen_codificada);`
This will return u bit array directly . Now u can use 
`BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options(); //
 options.inSampleSize = 8;`
to scale down your photograph .

Comment: The issue is solved with this:

decodedString = Base64.decode(imagen_codificada);
     System.gc();
     BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
     options.inSampleSize = 8;
     InputStream input = new      ByteArrayInputStream(decodedString);
           Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, 
             options); 
           menu.setNombreApellido(decodedByte);

Comment: @vicks630 : y are u calling inputStream ?